# passing multiple, comma separated, arguments to a custom << operator

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Is it possible to pass multiple arguments/have multiple parameters for a custom, overloaded, << operator in C++? And if it is, how to do it.

example:

```
MyClass &operator <<(int par1, int par2) {
            //do stuff with arguments

            //return current object to chain <<`s
            return *this;
        }
```

a more complex, implementation-wise, version of the code above is used in my current project, and I cant seem to call it normally separting arguments with commas:

```
MyClassObject << 4, 100;
```

how could I achieve this, preferably with a simple syntax, as anything complex would defeat the purpose of overloading operators. Note that I have already searched the interwebs, but found nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either you call it explicitly:

```
MyClassObject.operator<<(4,100);
```

Or you redefine it to take only a single argument, e.g.

```
MyClass &operator<<(std::array<int,2> par)
```

or

```
MyClass &operator<<(std::pair<int,int> par)
```

and then call it

```
MyClassObject << {4,100};
```

Comment: the lattermost seems to fit my needs- simple and readable syntax. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The latter form might use `std::tuple` as well for longer sequences.